# What programming language is used in The Martian?

Tags: computers, the-martian

What is the programming language displayed on screenshot?

[image: strange programming language]

Comment: Sweet jesus on a pancake, a non-monospaced font

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems like this is [PVS](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mvz/handouts/wift-tutorial.pdf), a Lisp variant language, also related to Prolog. See also the [PVS specification page](http://pvs.csl.sri.com/). This particular piece of code is from the [NASA PVS library](http://shemesh.larc.nasa.gov/people/cam/Bernstein/), and you can find it in `Bernstein/MPoly.pvs`.

Comment: See also https://shemesh.larc.nasa.gov/people/cam/TheMartian/

Answer (score 13):

The fragment you see in the image is indeed a piece of PVS, written by Anthony Narkawicz and Cesar Munoz, both of NASA Langley, Va, USA. However, it is *not* a programming language, but instead an interactive theorem prover.

There are two parts to the language: a way to state theorems (.pvs files) and a way to state proofs (.prf files). An example of the latter from one of my proofs can be seen in a still from the film using the link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv9rv.jpg).

Of course the real question is why Matt Damon's character needs a proof about properties of the exponential function to escape his predicament. Perhaps that will become apparent when I get to see the film!

Comment: +1 for a good answer, and for being based down the road from me :-)